# What is the cleanest way to add footer view to tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I would like to know, what is the cleanest and easiest way to add footer to tableview?

Now I do a hardcoding:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if viewModel.shouldShowPremiumBanner {
        let footerView: LibraryFooterView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooter()
        footerView.viewModel = LibraryFooterViewModel(navigator: Locator.navigator,
                                                      localStorage: Locator.localStorage)
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
        return footerView
    }
    return nil
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if viewModel.shouldShowPremiumBanner {
        return estimatedSectionFooterHeight
    }
    return .leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

Comment: which part of the code above you have issue with? You are returning footer view for all section if `viewModel.shouldShowPremiumBanner` is true but I believe that's your requirement other than that I dont see any issue

Comment: i would like to add this to tableview not in section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i would like to add this to tableview not in section

you are already doing it by setting `self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView`

as per docs

> Use this property to specify a footer view for your entire table. The
>   footer view is the last item to appear in the table's view's scrolling
>   content, and it is separate from the footer views you add to
>   individual sections. The default value of this property is nil.

link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614976-tablefooterview

So simply remove your `viewForFooterInSection` code and `viewDidLoad` of your viewController simply set

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let footerView: LibraryFooterView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooter()
    footerView.viewModel = LibraryFooterViewModel(navigator: Locator.navigator,
                                                  localStorage: Locator.localStorage)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
}
```

By writing `self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView` in `viewForFooterInSection` you are simply resetting the same variable agin and again with no actual visual change, and you are simply wasting CPU cycles by creating view and its viewModel again and again. Set it once may be in `viewDidLoad` or wherever it makes sense in your case and just leave it.

Hope it helps